# Dwindling Pool Mining Shares Ethpool

Tags: mining, mining-pools, shares

anyone notice lower share count over the last cpl days on ethpool? i'm humming along at my blazing 25 mh/s speed (lol) and have seen my share count go from ~22/hr to low teens or even ~10/hr lately. is there something going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and due to the mining difficulty rising in response to the additional hashpower being pointed at Ethereum.

As Ethereum becomes more and more profitable to mine, the additional miners make it harder (more difficult) for other miners in the network to find shares.

Comment: i understand that in an overall sense. i was referring more to the fact that there seemed to be a temporary drop in the last day or so. ie. maybe some system problems of some sort?....but the good news is seems to be getting better...just logged 18 shares last hour. so looks like it may be working itself out.....do u think bitcoin drop y'day may have caused what ur saying? temp bitcoin drop has miners looking elsewhere (eg ETH) for profits? thanks for your answer. appreciate it

Comment: If your miner was still running during that time, then there were no system problems.  Sometimes you can go through large swings in shares/hr, just based on the nothing other than the random nature of mining. I personally have seen swings as large as +/- 75% in my shares/hr.